# Freeze and black screen on distribution build - works fine in debug

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, freeze

I have made a really simple image browser app, no xibs, no advanced stuff. I use AFNetwork for JSON calls, and display some images in a scroll view (10 images)

It works like a charm when I just build straight to the device, but if I choose to make an adhoc build, the app freezes on a black screen. It doesn't even reach my root view controller...

It doesn't crash, so I have no crash reports, all i have in the console is this :

> mobile_house_arrest[4897] : Max open files: 125

How can code run in build, but fail on distribution ?

I have tried the following measures, without any luck:

- Tried removing the DEBUG = 1 variable from debug builds
- Changed the scheme so my build to device used the release scheme instead
- Turned off zombies and all other debug methods
- Tripplechecked signing, provisioning profiles ect

My build target is 6.0

My app delegate :

```
@implementation SCAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[SCTestViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this ? Or common things that work in debug, but not in release?

Comment: Were you able to resolve your problem ? Can you plz post solution if so ?